# JQuery Error Message in FireBug for Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, firebug

When I try to inspect data sent with Firebug Lite for Google Chrome, in the console tab I get "JQMIGRATE: jQuery.browser is deprecated". Firebug Lite version is 1.4.0.11967 and I can't see at all which data is sent. This happens in specific website pages only.

Comment: What is your actual question? If you can see all of the data what is the problem?

Comment: @davidpostill sorry I misspelled. I meant "I can't see". Edited.

Comment: Can you not use the built-in Chrome devtools? The error you are reporting is a standard warning message generated by the jQuery migration plugin, it isn't really something to worry about.